# How can I insert a line break in a Word document using DocX?

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I'm using [DocX](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX) (the library, not the file format) to programmatically create a word document from scratch using C#. It's all going really well except for one thing:

I want to add a paragraph that contains a code listing and I want the lines to be all contained in a single paragraph and separated with line breaks. My intent is to apply formatting to the paragraph (i.e. the entire code listing) once and not have to format each line individually.

By creating a simple document and examining it, I have determined that in the Office XML file, a line break maps to a `<w:br/>` element, but I can't see any way to add this within DocX. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand what you are looking for but maybe I could help. Maybe the approach with "\n" will be giving the expected result:

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Create("Test.docx"))
{               
            Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();
            p.Append("Hello World \nHello world!").Font(new FontFamily("Arial Black"));
            document.Save();
}
```

If I didn't get it right maybe [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-DOCX-ef1741b1) article will help you solve the problem.

Comment: You know, that seems really obvious now, but I never thought to try simply adding a '\n'! Will give that a go ASAP.

Comment: OK, so it turns out that there's an AppendLine() method that appends a line break. I had originally thought it was creating a new paragraph but closer inspection shows that it's actually using line breaks, which is what I want. However, I can't get my formatting to apply to the whole paragraph. If I apply formatting to the paragraph before I append the lines, then it's simply ignored. If I apply formatting to the paragraph after I append the lines, then only the last line is formatted. So I currently have to apply formatting to every line, which doubles the size of the document!